# JQuery Droppable does not accept draggable items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I am working on a HTML/jQuery DnD project. The images that I want to be draggable are so but the targets don't accept them. Even though droppable, the `td` elements that should accept the images don't accept anything.

What version of jQuery and jQueryUI are the least ones I should use? What else have I forgotten/done wrong? TIA for your answers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tierspiel</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Freya Bremer">
  <style>
    body {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .target {
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: black;
      border-style: solid;
      margin-right: 1em;
      margin-top: 1em;
      empty-cells: show;
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 1 em;
    }
    
    table {
      align: center;
    }
    
    td img {
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: black;
      border-style: solid;
      margin-right: 1em;
      margin-top: 1em;
    }
    
    tr {
      margin-right: 1em;
      margin-top: 1em;
    }
    
    th {
      color: #b00000;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-right: 1em;
      margin-top: 1em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    [draggable=true] {
      cursor: grab;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    init();

    function init() {
      $(".tier").draggable();

      console.log("Tier draggable");

      $(".target").droppable({
        accept: ".tier",
        tolerance: "touch",
        drop: checkclass
      });
      console.log("Target droppable");

    }

    function checkclass() {

      console.log("Checkclass läuft");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">
  <p>Liebe Schüler,<br> Ihr kennt Euch ja schon mit Tieren aus und habt auch schon gelernt, daß man Tiere in Klassen einteilt.<br> Damit kommen wir zu einem kleinen Spiel.<br> Unten seht Ihr Bilder von einigen Tieren und auch die Klassen, zu denen diese
    Tiere gehören.<br> Ihr bitte nehmt die Bilder der Tiere in die Hand und zieht sie in die Klasse, <br> wo Ihr wißt, daß sie dazu gehören.<br> Es gibt für Säugetiere, Amphibien und Reptilien jeweils 3 dazu passende Tiere.<br> Ihr schafft das sicher
    ganz alleine, aber wenn etwas zu schwierig ist helfen Euch Eure Lehrer sicher gerne.<br> Fangen wir also an...
  </p>
  <p>Hier kommen unsere Tiere:</p>
  <table align="center">
    <tr align="center">
      <td><img src="tier1.jpg" draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
      <td><img src="tier2.jpg" draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
      <td><img src="tier3.jpg" draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
      <tr align="center">
        <td><img src="tier4.jpg" draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
        <td><img src="tier5.jpg" draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
        <td><img src="tier6.jpg" draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td><img src="tier7.jpg" draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
        <td><img src="tier8.jpg" draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
        <td><img src="tier9.jpg" draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  <p>Die Klassen brauchen wir auch noch. Hier sind sie.</p>

  <table align="center">
    <tr align="center">
      <th align="center">Säugetiere</th>
      <th align="center">Amphibien</th>
      <th align="center">Reptilien</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="target" droppable="true"></td>
      <td class="target" droppable="true"></td>
      <td class="target" droppable="true"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="target"></td>
      <td class="target"></td>
      <td class="target"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="target"></td>
      <td class="target"></td>
      <td class="target"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also note that the versions of jQuery and jQueryUI you're using are massively outdated. In fact they are both over 10 years old! Update jQuery to version 3.6 and jQueryUI to 1.12.1. Note that this won't directly affect your issue, but will fix any performance and security problems you may encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tier").draggable({
    cursor: "grab"
  });
  $(".target.droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".tier",
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function(evt, ui) {
      ui.draggable.attr("style", "").appendTo(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.target {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  empty-cells: show;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1 em;
}

table {
  align: center;
}

td img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

tr {
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

th {
  color: #b00000;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Liebe Schüler,<br> Ihr kennt Euch ja schon mit Tieren aus und habt auch schon gelernt, daß man Tiere in Klassen einteilt.<br> Damit kommen wir zu einem kleinen Spiel.<br> Unten seht Ihr Bilder von einigen Tieren und auch die Klassen, zu denen diese Tiere
  gehören.
  <br> Ihr bitte nehmt die Bilder der Tiere in die Hand und zieht sie in die Klasse, <br> wo Ihr wißt, daß sie dazu gehören.<br> Es gibt für Säugetiere, Amphibien und Reptilien jeweils 3 dazu passende Tiere.<br> Ihr schafft das sicher ganz alleine, aber
  wenn etwas zu schwierig ist helfen Euch Eure Lehrer sicher gerne.<br> Fangen wir also an...
</p>
<p>Hier kommen unsere Tiere:</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="tier1.jpg" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="tier2.jpg" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="tier3.jpg" class="tier"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="tier4.jpg" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="tier5.jpg" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="tier6.jpg" class="tier"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="tier7.jpg" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="tier8.jpg" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="tier9.jpg" class="tier"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Die Klassen brauchen wir auch noch. Hier sind sie.</p>
<table align="center">
  <tr align="center">
    <th align="center">Säugetiere</th>
    <th align="center">Amphibien</th>
    <th align="center">Reptilien</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="target droppable"></td>
    <td class="target droppable"></td>
    <td class="target droppable"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="target"></td>
    <td class="target"></td>
    <td class="target"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="target"></td>
    <td class="target"></td>
    <td class="target"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Draggable will apply Styling to the element. It can often be best to strip this before appending it to the Drop target.

In regards to the Demo, please see https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#accepted-elements You can see the versions used here. I would advise using more modern version of jQuery; yet this would be as low as I would suggest.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so very much! It took only a very slight change (changing the tolerance "touch" to "pointer" to do exactly what I wanted it to do. Thank you gain very much.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the `droppable` attribute to `data-droppable` since the former is an invalid attribute. After you make that change, change the `$.droppable` selector to: `.target[data-droppable="true"]`. I also did this with the `draggable` attributes, but these were not the immediate issue, because you never utilized them.

Furthermore, I used versions 3.3.1 and 1.12.1 of jQuery and jQuery UI respectively. These are the latest available versions via cdnjs.

**Note:** I also created a jQuery plugin function called `$.fn.centerOnDrop` that centers the draggable item in the droppable zone.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.centerOnDrop = function(ui) {
    ui.draggable.position({
      my: 'center',
      at: 'center',
      of: this,
      using: function(pos) {
        $(this).animate(pos, 200, 'linear');
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

init();

function init() {
  $('.tier[data-draggable="true"]').draggable();
  console.log('Tier draggable');
  $('.target[data-droppable="true"]').droppable({
    accept: '.tier',
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: checkClass
  });
  console.log('Target droppable');
}

function checkClass(event, ui) {
  console.log('checkClass is running');
  $(this).centerOnDrop(ui);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

a,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.target {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  empty-cells: show;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1 em;
}

table {
  align: center;
}

td img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

tr {
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

th {
  color: #b00000;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

[draggable=true] {
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Liebe Schüler,<br> Ihr kennt Euch ja schon mit Tieren aus und habt auch schon gelernt, daß man Tiere in Klassen einteilt.<br> Damit kommen wir zu einem kleinen Spiel.<br> Unten seht Ihr Bilder von einigen Tieren und auch die Klassen, zu denen diese Tiere
  gehören.
  <br> Ihr bitte nehmt die Bilder der Tiere in die Hand und zieht sie in die Klasse, <br> wo Ihr wißt, daß sie dazu gehören.<br> Es gibt für Säugetiere, Amphibien und Reptilien jeweils 3 dazu passende Tiere.<br> Ihr schafft das sicher ganz alleine, aber
  wenn etwas zu schwierig ist helfen Euch Eure Lehrer sicher gerne.<br> Fangen wir also an...
</p>
<p>Hier kommen unsere Tiere:</p>
<table align="center">
  <tr align="center">
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Tier+1" data-draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Tier+2" data-draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Tier+3" data-draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Tier+4" data-draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Tier+5" data-draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Tier+6" data-draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Tier+7" data-draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Tier+8" data-draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Tier+9" data-draggable="true" class="tier"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Die Klassen brauchen wir auch noch. Hier sind sie.</p>

<table align="center">
  <tr align="center">
    <th align="center">Mammals</th>
    <th align="center">Amphibians</th>
    <th align="center">Reptiles</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="target" data-droppable="true"></td>
    <td class="target" data-droppable="true"></td>
    <td class="target" data-droppable="true"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="target"></td>
    <td class="target"></td>
    <td class="target"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="target"></td>
    <td class="target"></td>
    <td class="target"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have copied your code 1 to 1 into my project and while the code-snippet here works perfectly, the problem still persists in my project. The code-droppable tds still don't accept anything. I am using Firefox, Chrome and MS Edge browsers and it works in neither. I have controlled and re-read it so often that my eyes started to shed tears...

Comment: @Swordswoman69 if you noticed, I altered the HTML, so take that into consideration.